# Ansible: How to filter dict2items and run playbook only for the matched values

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a dict playbook which looks like this:

```
  x_php_versions_installed:
      ea-php71:
        - ea-php71-php-bcmath
        - ea-php71-php-xmlrpc
        - ea-php71-php-zip
        - pecl-memcached
        - pecl-imagick
      ea-php72:
        - ea-php72-php-cli
        - ea-php72-php-common
        - ea-php72-php-curl
        - pecl-imagick
```

I would like to filter them, to write me each item.value which contains 'ea' string but not everything else. My task looks like this:

```
- name: Write out only the ea packages
  debug:
    msg: '{{ item.value }}'
  when: item.value | selectattr(item.value, 'contains', 'ea')
  loop: '{{ x_php_versions_installed | dict2items }}
```

But it does not work, because it will list all of the packages, not only the ea ones. The expected answer should look like this:

```
...
"msg": [
    "ea-php71-php-bcmath",
    "ea-php71-php-xmlrpc",
    "ea-php71-php-zip"
]
...
"msg": [
    "ea-php72-php-cli",
    "ea-php72-php-common",
    "ea-php72-php-curl"
]
...
```

Another possibility is to filter out the 'pecl' string, it will gave me the same result and it also works fine.

Comment: I'd probably use with_items rather than loop. Also with Ansible it pays to sneak up on things. So start with just the with_items and then add your when. Last but not least I often use -vvv to get lots of output to study, may not help in this case though.

Comment: As far as I know, with_items will be deprecated, the ansible docs are suggesting to use loop instead. I just followed the documentation.

Comment: Drat then I'll have a few playbooks to update. The rest of the point still stands sneak up on the solution bit by bit. With @Vladimirs solution below I would have done just item.value with -vvv very very verbose mode on. BTW another fave of mine is meta: end_play to stop just after the point I'm debugging up to in a playbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"Filter item.value which contains `ea` string."***

A: The task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value|select('match','^ea-(.*)$')|list }}"
      loop: "{{ x_php_versions_installed|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```
  msg:
  - ea-php71-php-bcmath
  - ea-php71-php-xmlrpc
  - ea-php71-php-zip

  msg:
  - ea-php72-php-cli
  - ea-php72-php-common
  - ea-php72-php-curl
```

---

Note: The test [*match*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) by default *"succeeds if it finds the pattern at the beginning of the string"*. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value|select('match', 'ea-')|list }}"
      loop: "{{ x_php_versions_installed|dict2items }}"
```

---

Q: ***"Filter out the `pecl` string."***

A: Change the filter to *`reject`* and fit the *regex*. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value|reject('match','^pecl-(.*)$')|list }}"
      loop: "{{ x_php_versions_installed|dict2items }}"
```

---

Notes:

- Select the lists without iteration. Declare the variables

```yaml
  x_php_versions_installed_keys: "{{ x_php_versions_installed.keys()|list }}"
  x_php_versions_installed_ea_vals: "{{ x_php_versions_installed|dict2items|
                                        map(attribute='value')|
                                        map('select', 'match', 'ea-')|list }}"
  x_php_versions_installed_ea: "{{ dict(x_php_versions_installed_keys|
                                        zip(x_php_versions_installed_ea_vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  x_php_versions_installed_ea:
    ea-php71:
    - ea-php71-php-bcmath
    - ea-php71-php-xmlrpc
    - ea-php71-php-zip
    ea-php72:
    - ea-php72-php-cli
    - ea-php72-php-common
    - ea-php72-php-curl
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    x_php_versions_installed:
      ea-php71:
        - ea-php71-php-bcmath
        - ea-php71-php-xmlrpc
        - ea-php71-php-zip
        - pecl-memcached
        - pecl-imagick
      ea-php72:
        - ea-php72-php-cli
        - ea-php72-php-common
        - ea-php72-php-curl
        - pecl-imagick

    x_php_versions_installed_keys: "{{ x_php_versions_installed.keys()|list }}"
    x_php_versions_installed_ea_vals: "{{ x_php_versions_installed|dict2items|
                                          map(attribute='value')|
                                          map('select', 'match', 'ea-')|list }}"
    x_php_versions_installed_ea: "{{ dict(x_php_versions_installed_keys|
                                          zip(x_php_versions_installed_ea_vals)) }}"

  tasks:
    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value|select('match','^ea-(.*)$')|list }}"
      loop: "{{ x_php_versions_installed|dict2items }}"
    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value|select('match', 'ea-')|list }}"
      loop: "{{ x_php_versions_installed|dict2items }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value|reject('match','^pecl-(.*)$')|list }}"
      loop: "{{ x_php_versions_installed|dict2items }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value|reject('match','pecl-')|list }}"
      loop: "{{ x_php_versions_installed|dict2items }}"

    - debug:
        var: x_php_versions_installed_ea
```